# Injection of Exception classes

Tags: c#, exception, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

I am implementing an MVC site, using Dependency Injection. I have view models that can encounter errors. We'd thought that the best way to communicate these errors back to the relevant controllers would be to throw some custom exceptions.

My problem: I would like to derive these exceptions from a common base class that would write information about the error that has occurred to a log. But since we're using DI, our logging object is constructed and controlled by our IoC container. To date, all of our objects that have needed logging have been constructed and initialized by the IoC container. But these exceptions will be created on-the-fly.

What's the most common way to deal with this? I can see how I might create an ExceptionFactory class, inject the logger into it, and then inject it into the view models. But that doesn't seem very IoC'ish.

Is there a common idiom for dealing with this situation?

Comment: Wait. Your view models have logic? I would say that this is the core of your problem. MVC view models should be behaviorless. The controller should contain the logic and both views and view models should be dumb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would shy away from having your exception object being coupled with a logger. I could see an exception object knowing how to format it's exception message, but not log it.

Catch the exception upstream where it is relevant and log it there. If your IoC container supports it you can use interception to catch and log exceptions there. I would provide some links but it's probably better off you just Google IoC and interceptions and decide what you need based on your chosen framework.

Just my $0.02 cents, hope this helps.

Comment: Google's IOC container is in java AFAIK, and it sucks.

Comment: The whole point of logging inside the exception is so that every thrown exception is logged. I agree that we don't want to bind an exception class to any specific implementation of a logger, but I don't see a problem in injecting an instance of a logger interface.

Comment: My opinion comes from the way I use exceptions. I typically don't log an exception until it is caught, and if it is not caught then the global exception handler will catch and log it. Because of this the act of logging is a separate concern. If exceptions are being caught and thrown correctly they should contain the entire call stack and .ToString() the exception should reveal all. Since the controller is already catching these exceptions why not log them as well. Also, I try to keep the customization in my exceptions very light - wouldn't want an exception while throwing an exception.

Answer (score 0):

You can use decorator or interceptors for this purpose.

Logging or error filters are cross cutting concerns and there is no penalty nor anything wrong with writing them in your controllers.

Also, you can still inject them into whatever you want.

Everything doesnt have to be IOC'ish. as long as it works, it should be fine.

Comment: If I were injecting an object, I could create a decorator and inject an instance of that, instead. But in this case, I'm not injecting an object at all, so I don't see how creating a decorator would help.

Comment: Did you look at elmah ?